# GeoServer OpenLayers layer preview in on localhost:port URL and fails outside the machine

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, iis, localhost

After GeoServer has been installed on port 8080, and has been configured to work on with a unique domain in the Proxy Base URL, the Layer preview was still failing. The new page opened on the URL set in the Proxy base URL, but the ol.css, ol.js and the layer content itself was looking at an address like https://localhost:8080/openlayers3/ol.css, (or the layer Store and path in instead OpenLayers3).

There has been a IIS URL Rewrite set up for the URL I set in the Proxy Base URL. That IIS site has to run, in order to make the GeoServer opening page running. When I stop the IIS, I cannot open the GeoServer's main page either.

With this setup my GeoServer's layer preview work fine on this machine, but when I open GeoServer from an other machine on the network (they just on our intranet), that the layer Preview fails, as there is no layer on that machines localhost:port setup.

Comment: known issue - just log on to the local machine to use the layer preview

Answer (score 2):

I think I have found a solution.
I could access a working layer preview from other machine than the host one, as long as the domain is accessable from that machine.

I needed to add the port number to the into the Proxy Base URL. In that case the Layer preview used the the entire URL with the added port, when it was requesting the content of the OpenLayers.

It had a running IIS with the domian in the binding. But it was not needed to make a URL rewrite rule. That has solved the issue on my machines.

It might not be the most elegant, as the port is shown in the URL, but it did make it accessable.

Answer (score 0):

I have now found a way to make the openlayers layer preview work as well, from outside the network where Geoserver is installed.

Reaching your domain from outside will is needed, but not enough to access the openlayers, as that one will look for your layer either on localhost, IP and Geoserver's port.

I needed to set up an ISAPI worker on IIS, to handle request coming from outside. With that one can have a free use of their payer preview from anywhere where your Geoserver site is visible from.